# builder.Configuration.GetValue<string[]> return null

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am using .NET 6. In my `program.cs`, I have an issue that `allowedOriginUrl is null`. I want to get the value from appsettings.json to be in the string array.

```
var allowedOriginUrl = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string[]>("AllowedOriginUrl");
```

In my appsettings.json

```
{
  "AllowedOriginUrl": [ "https://localhost:123", "https://localhost:321" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetValue<T>` method  works perfectly for a string or a boolean value. However if you use the same code to try and get the array of strings from the AllowedOriginUrl property, you will get null returned.

To get an array of values from the appsettings configuration file you need two lines of code instead of one. First of all we use the GetSection method to grab the whole set of strings as an object, and then use the `Get<T>` method instead of `GetValue<T>`.

```
//get the list of strings as an object
var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOriginUrl");

//the Get<T> method attempts to bind any value with the given type 
//to the new property, in this case 'values' 
string[] values = section.Get<string[]>();
```

result:

[image]